# При вставке статьи из JSON отображаются HTML теги - (React / Next JS)

Tags: html, json, reactjs, nextjs

У меня есть многолетний проект, созданный на Joomla. Используя REST API Джумлы получил JSON из базы данных MySQL. Задача - обновить сайт и сделать его на Next, параллельно попрактиковаться.
Столкнулся с проблемой - при вставке тела статьи в компонент, в браузере отображаются все теги. Перечитал множество форумов, но как решить вопрос на Реакт, так и не нашел.

Ссылка на пример получаемого JSON:
https://sketchok.com/api/v1/content/item/1902

Ниже привел код компонента

Буду очень признателен за подсказку!

```
export default class Article extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: null,
    body: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://sketchok.com/api/v1/content/item/1902")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          title: data.article.title,
          body: data.article.fulltext
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
        <div>{this.state.body}</div>
        <Link href="/">
          <a>Home</a>
        </Link>
        <p>Text</p>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Надо выпилить теги или отрендерить в DOM?

Comment: Нужно было отрендерить DOM, вопрос решил с помощью свойства dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Спасибо за комментарий!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст как HTML в реакте можно вставить при помощи "[dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)"

В вашем случае код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```js
export default class Article extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: null,
    body: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://sketchok.com/api/v1/content/item/1902")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          title: data.article.title,
          body: data.article.fulltext
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
  const {title, body} = this.state;
  const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
  
  const formattedTitle = title.replace(regex, ''),
        formattedBody = body.replace(regex, '');
  
    return (
      <Layout>
        <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:formattedTitle}} />
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:formattedBody}} />
        <Link href="/">
          <a>Home</a>
        </Link>
        <p>Text</p>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Именно то, что нужно было. Теперь все отображается корректно! Единственное, в моем случае не понадобилось исключать Regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Можно решить это с помощью регулярного выражения и код будет выглядеть так

```js
const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
const result = data.description.replace(regex, '')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! В этом случае содержимое отображается как текст. Задача в том, чтобы теги несли свой функционал. То есть, нужно получить не просто текст, а чтобы содержимое отображалось, как форматированный HTML блок.

Comment: тогда я не совсем понимаю суть вопроса, ты можешь просто отстилизовать получаемые теги так как тебе нужно, не вижу проблемы

Comment: Я видимо не совсем точно описал проблему. Дело в том, что при вставке данных с html тегами из json в реакт, все отображается в одной куче - теги, текст, ссылки на картинки, вместо самих изображений и т.д. Мне нужно было не избавиться от тегов, а чтобы они учитывались браузером и выполняли свой функционал. Решением оказалось свойство dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Еще раз спасибо за ответ, решение с регулярными выражениями пригодилось в другом вопросе :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML в реакте можно вставить при помощи "dangerouslySetInnerHTML".

При этом есть опасность XSS атаки.

Для защиты можно использовать библиотеку: https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify

```
function RawHTML({dirtyHTML}) {
  const cleanHTML = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirtyHTML)
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: cleanHTML}} />;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Уже в процессе установки этой библиотеки. dangerouslySetInnerHTML оказался искомым решением